# Cannot connect from host to mongo using docker-compose

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I'm running my mongo db with docker-compose

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: mongo:4
    ports: 
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - ./storage/mongo:/data/db:rw
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin123
    command: --smallfiles --bind_ip_all --port 27017
```

When I do

```
$> docker-compose exec db bash
```

I can simply connect to my db

```
$> mongo -u admin -p admin123
```

However, when I do the same thing from my host system I cannot connect

```
(master) ✗ mongo -u admin -p admin123                                 
MongoDB shell version v4.0.3
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("8689631e-ac9c-40f8-aa2a-e55f6103224f") }
MongoDB server version: 4.0.9
2019-05-11T17:44:19.181+0200 E QUERY    [js] Error: Authentication failed. :
DB.prototype._authOrThrow@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1685:20
@(auth):6:1
@(auth):1:2
exception: login failed
```

I also tried with `--host 0.0.0.0` but same result. Below is the listing of `ps`

```
$> docker-compose ps
       Name                      Command               State                                  Ports                                
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       db_1         docker-entrypoint.sh --sma ...     Up      0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp
```

I get the feeling that mongo doesn't accept remote connections, which is why I added `command: --smallfiles --bind_ip_all --port 27017` but it didn't help. Any suggestion what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: try with specifying host in your mongo cli command like this --host localhost:27017

Comment: nope, ` --host localhost:27017` gives the same result

Comment: It is actually strange because I used your docker-compose file and I managed to connect to the container from the host using Robo 3T GUI.

Comment: I've done this in the past without issues too, weird :( Can you maybe try to run it the same way, with `docker-compose` and try to connect with a local mongo client?

Comment: I've created an other post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56097915/equivalent-of-docker-option-config-in-docker-compose) which might solve the issue, maybe!

Comment: I have installed mongo shell and connected to container started by your compose. I installed shell with version 4.0.9. You are using 4.0.3. I think that it might be problem with your shell client or maybe host OS.

Comment: I changed the mongo image to 4.0.3 with the same result. If I remove the `environment` from the docker-compose file all works fine. So it has to do with that and the authentication part. The command that is running inside the container is `mongod --smallfiles --bind_ip_all --port 27017 --auth`