# equivalent of docker option --config in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to run mongo with docker-compose. From the [docker mongo page](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo) I have the following command

```
$> docker run --name some-mongo -v /my/custom:/etc/mongo -d mongo --config /etc/mongo/mongod.conf

version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: mongo:4
    ports: 
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - ./storage/mongo:/data/db:rw
```

Now I would also like to define the mongod.conf; `--config /etc/mongo/mongod.conf` but how can you do that inside docker-compose?

Answer (score 0):

The `--config` is part of `mongo`, not `docker`. You may still use it with `docker-compose` like

```sh
docker-compose run db --config /etc/mongo/mongod.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`command`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#command)

```
services:
  db:
    image: mongo:4
    command: "mongo --config /etc/mongo/mongod.conf" 
    ports: 
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - ./storage/mongo:/data/db:rw
```